# Given Y cards with replacement, how many distinct cards are above a minimum threshold?

Tags: probability, expected-value

You have a set of playing cards with 15 unique cards in it and no more. You are given 5 cards per minute, with replacement. You need 20 cards of a specific kind to get a stamp of the card type. So, there are 15 stamps to earn.

let cards(t) = the number of cards earned at a given minute

What is the probability of having x specific stamps (20 cards or more of that kind to earn it's stamp) given cards(t) cards?

---

My rough work below

> let cards(t) = the number of cards earned at a given time
>
> P(getting a specific stamp card) = 1/num stamps to get
>
> P(getting 19 or less cards of a specific stamp) = cumulative binomial
>   distribution (19 successes,  cards(t) draws, P(getting a specific
>   stamp card))
>
> P(unlocking a specific stamps (20 cards or more of that stamp) ) as =
>   1 - P(getting 19 or less cards of a specific stamp)
>
> So from this we expand to unlocking x specific stamps:
>
> P(getting 19 or less cards of a specific stamp * x stamps ) =
>   cumulative binomial distribution (19 successes * x?,  cards(t) draws,
>   P(getting a specific stamp card) * x? )
>
> *! This part below definitely doesn't work because you can unlock 0..x-1
>   stamps and still not unlock x specific stamps. I'm not sure what
>   type of summation or equation I should use to calculate this part*
>
> P(unlocking a x specific stamps (20 cards or more of each stamp) ) as
>   = 1 - P(getting 19 or less cards of a specific stamp * x stamps )
>
> let X = random variable with x=0..numStamps outcomes with P(unlocking
>   a x specific stamps (20 cards or more of each stamp) ) probability
>
> # stamps expected to be unlocked would be: E[X] = Sum x=1..numStamps( P(unlocking a x specific stamps (20 cards or more of each stamp) )  *
>   x )

---

I'm having trouble with the minimums thresholds of the 'buckets' when I try to calculate the probability of unlocking x stamps.

P(unlocking a x specific stamps (20 cards or more of each stamp) ) 
= 1 - Sum y=0..x-1 ( 
P(unlocking a y specific stamps (20 cards or more of each stamp) 
)

^ something inductive like this might work but it may be more difficult than what this requires

Answer (score 0):

The closed form math for this ended up being too hard, so I wrote a small script to simulate the draws instead and plotted the averages/distribution.

Someday I'd love to learn the math to get this working!